# Optimizing Factor Analysis implementation in R - Maximum Likelihood

Tags: r, factor-analysis

In order to learn more about Factor Analysis, I've tried to implement a common model in R by hand, using MLE.

So I simulated data ( data ~ beta_1 + beta_2*x) . I employed PCA for generating starting values for X, and a normal distribution sample for betas.
After defining a log likelihood, I started to run the iterations.

However, it takes so long to converge (although it does after one hour). I'm unsure if it is related to some adjustment I overlooked.

Anyway, my question is: is there some way of optimizing these iterations and estimating factor loadings in less time? If so, what are my mistakes here?

```
# Generating data
nbetas <- 100
nxs <- 36

betas <- matrix(rnorm(2*nbetas), ncol=2)
xs <- rnorm(nxs)
results <- matrix(0, nrow=nxs, ncol=nbetas)
for (i in 1:nxs)
  for (j in 1:nbetas)
    results[i,j] <- betas[j,1] + betas[j,2]*xs[i]


# A simple PCA recovers the xs
plot(cmdscale(dist(results))[,1], xs)

# Log Likelihood function
norm.loglike <- function(betas_h,xs_h,values) {
  print(class(betas_h))
  soma <- 0
  for (i in 1:nxs)
    for (j in 1:nbetas)
      soma <- soma + dnorm(values[i,j], mean=(betas_h[j] + betas_h[j+nbetas]*xs_h[i])) 
# It seems that optim doesn't take on matrix, so I'm dealing with a vector 
  print(-soma)
  return(-soma)
}


xs_new <- cmdscale(dist(results))[,1] # starting values for x

# First estimation
betas_new <- optim(matrix(rnorm(nbetas*2), ncol=2), norm.loglike, method="L-BFGS-B",xs_h=xs_new, values=results)$par

# Iterations
for (i in 1:30) {
  print(i)
  xs_new <- optim(xs_new, norm.loglike, "L-BFGS-B",betas=betas_new, values=results)$par
  betas_new <- optim(betas_new, norm.loglike, method="L-BFGS-B",xs=xs_new, values=results)$par
}

# Plotting graphs to check them
plot(xs,xs_new)
plot(betas[,1], betas_new[,1])
plot(betas[,2], betas_new[,2])
```

Comment: If I am not mistaken, factorial solutions are undetermined (up to the product by an orthogonal matrix). Therefore, I would think that in order to achieve convergence to a single point  you should give some conditions, for otherwise there is an infinity of points with equal likelihood.

Comment: Thank you. But what conditions in this case?

Comment: Any you see fit. You might choose for instance to have 'beta2' to have a triangle of zeros, that will insure uniqueness of the solution, I think.

Comment: Did you consult with some existing algorithm of ML FA extraction or invented yours from scratch? For example, SPSS provides the algo [here](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLVMB_22.0.0/com.ibm.spss.statistics.algorithms/alg_factor.htm).

Comment: @F.Tusell , references?

Comment: @ttnphns, I invented mine from scratch. I'd like to consult some existing algorithm

Comment: Harman, "Modern Factor Analysis", See in particular section 6.4 ("...one maximum likelihood solution differs from another by a rotation. To remove this inherent indeterminacy, the computing algorithm must provide some side condition which fixes the particular solution.")

Comment: You should be using expectation-maximization (EM) algorithm instead of using general solver to mazimize the likelihood. It should converge in seconds.

Comment: @amoeba , I know, but I'm not trying expectation-maximization, but joint maximum likelihood.

Comment: EM converges to ML, that's the whole point.

Comment: That is not my point. I'm trying to implement another algorithm in order to show it to my students

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my programmmatic approach. This function, `norm.loglike2.2()`, is over 10 times faster than your `norm.loglike()` on my env (this function is exchangeable for yours because of the same arguments and return values).

```
norm.loglike2.2 <- function(betas_h, xs_h, values){
  print(class(betas_h))
  mean_mat <- betas_h[1:nbetas] + matrix(betas_h[(1+nbetas):(2*nbetas)], ncol=1) %*% xs_h
  soma_v <- dnorm(values, t(mean_mat))
  soma <- sum(soma_v)
  print(-soma)
  return(-soma)
}
```

Comment: As far as I understand from your argument, did you just implement the same function in a matrix form or did you do something else?

Comment: @Guilherme Duarte; Yes, I just avoided using `for()` loop and took a vector and matrix based method to shorten a time for calculation. What it does is the same as yours.

Comment: Indeed it is way faster. I'm looking for other solutions, though. I implemented with for() for didactic reasons. Anyway, based on my question, if no one answers here, I'll check your answer as correct.

Comment: @Guilherme Duarte; You don’t have to do that. I understood my answer isn't essential.

Answer (score 2):

This is not quite an answer, but too long for a comment. Let the observed multivariate variable be according to the factor model:

$\boldsymbol{X} = A\boldsymbol{F} + \boldsymbol{\epsilon}$

Then the covariance matrix of the $\boldsymbol{X}$ will be
$\Sigma = AA' + \Psi$ where $\Psi$ is the diagonal matrix of variances of the unique factors. Clearly, $A$ cannot be unique, for any $A_* = AG$   with $G$ orthogonal will produce exactly the same $\Sigma$:

$\Sigma = AA' + \Psi =  A_*A_*' + \Psi$

One way of making $A$ unique is to force it to have (for instance) an upper triangle of zeros. This also reduces the number of parameters over which you have to optimize. A quick surge with Google turned up

https://stat.ethz.ch/~maathuis/teaching/fall08/Notes5.pdf

In page 18 you can find sketched the idea of how to implement a ML factor estimation.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about the upper triangle.  Looks like the link you provided is dead, do you have an alternate resource you can share?